An editor thinks a correction should be posted on the author's website rather than published. Is he sticking to the academic ethics?
I had a casual chat about a famous paper in mathematical economics with an editor of a journal different from where the paper was published. We agree that some of the mathematical results are mistaken.
Later I write to him asking for coauthoring a paper about the mistakes. He said something like:

I feel uncomfortable writing a correction not initiated by the author
and I feel a correction should be something posted on the original authors' website (rather than published by someone else).

What I learned from this site is that journals must correct a mistake once it is identified. So I start to feel that the editor's suggestions might not be ethical, even though I thought he was good person. I am unsure of my gut feeling.

"What I learned from this site is that journals must correct a mistake once it is identified."  I'm curious what you read that makes it out to be so absolute.  My impression, from this site and general experience, is that it is very much a judgment call on the part of the editors.

To clarify, is this "editor" specifically an editor of the same journal where the erroneous paper was published?

Nate Eldredge: Can you post this as the answer.

I have tried replacing "corrupted" with a more neutral term. OP, feel free to reject the edit or change the text again if you think this wording does not reflect what you wanted to ask.

@NateEldredge The paper is on another journal

@FedericoPoloni "Bad-faith" might be a bit subjective. How about using the terms ethical (or not)?

Ok, thanks for editing!

On one reasonable interpretation, the statement "I feel a correction should be something posted on the original authors' website (rather than published by someone else)" seems to present a false dichotomy: it does not allow the case that the original authors write a correction and publish it in a journal (presumably the one where the original paper appeared).  In my opinion this is the "correct" course of action.

I think referring to "the" editor in the title is rather misleading given that it is not their journal.

@NateEldredge These are where I learnt that we are obliged to correct a mistakes (exclude typo and grammars): https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/132988/found-and-corrected-a-mistake-on-someones-else-paper-praxis https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/85506/acknowledging-a-mistake-in-research https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83548/how-to-fix-a-mistake-in-an-accepted-paper and many more!

Since the "editor" is from a different journal, I think that their statement is perfectly reasonable and there are no ethical issues here. Academic courtesy, perhaps, but not ethics.
There is no real reason that another party can't publish corrections to published work. After all, it is sometimes impossible for the original authors, having died, to do so. It is courteous, however, to give them the opportunity to do so when possible.
Yes, a publisher should publish corrections to their published work, again, when possible, and it is preferable, not essential, that the originators of the correction be the original authors. However, it sometimes happens that corrections, being judged insignificant, aren't published.
You might check again with that "editor" you spoke with and see if their real intent was, not so much the "website" of the authors, but the website of the publishers of the authors. Personal websites often have little impact or visibility.
They were probably correct in that one publisher might be hesitant to "step on the toes" of another by publishing corrections or by participating in writing a correction in such a case. I think you are free to write such a correction if you wish, but ideally it should be more than a simple correction, somehow extending the original paper if possible. But, again, it seems to me to not be a question of ethics, but courtesy and you could just as well inform the authors and suggest a correction. You could even suggest your participation in the writing.

Great answer and I appreciate you a lot. Just a quick question. Are you sure that if the mistake is insignificant then it wouldn't be publicized? I thought the academia praise rigidity, especially in those math-related fields. Moreover, while professionals can identify those "small mistakes" while reading, the general public might not be able to.

Academic publications have an "intended audience", which probably doesn't include the general public. Some errors won't be corrected if they are deemed insignificant by that intended audience. Perhaps they should be, but there is a cost/benefit calculation in all such things.

Many thanks. Both answers are really good and I am having a hard time deciding which one to accept

SHORT ANSWER:

If correcting the mistakes does not change the main results of the "famous paper in mathematical economics", doing so (in the original paper, does not make sense doing so in a separate one) is no more important than correcting typographical errors in it: it will be up  to the editor of the journal where it was published (and potentially the authors) to decide whether it is worth it in a "corrected version" (and they might mention you in the acknowledgment part of the new version).

If correcting the mistakes does change (some of) the main results, trying to "get a paper out of it" without checking with the original authors and/or editors would be awkward and at the border of what is ethically acceptable (in the sense that it fails to promote a good spirit in the community). Unless you are already in conflict with them, it would be only good manners to inform  them of the mistakes that you identified and to let you answer privately before announcing such mistakes publicly.


LONGER ANSWER:

If you believe that you found some mathematical mistakes in "a famous paper in mathematical economics", it might be worth an email with the corresponding author of the article to check that those are indeed mistakes (as opposed to your own misunderstanding). Checking with a friend, whether they are editing another journal or not, is not enough to insure that you are correct in identifying mistakes.

If the corresponding author is unresponsive, and you are certain of the mistakes, it might be worth contacting the editor of the journal which published the original article and to offer to publish an "errata", which they can point out along with the original article on their website.

Only if both the authors and the editor of the original article are unresponsive should you consider writing an additional article to point out the mistakes, but even then the editor will consider whether it is worth it, and whether it will be seen as one of those practices from "predatory journals" which aim to maximize their "ranking" as measured by private companies.

Probably, the authors publishing an errata on their website is not enough, but I do not think that an editor of an unrelated journal proposing it as a reasons not to publish an errata in their own journal to be a failure in ethics: they are probably just being polite mentioning the first alternative which comes to their mind.



May I ask why you think publishing a correction for someone else is "bad spirit"? Publishing a correction is helping the original authors to refine their theory and helping the public a chance to access the updated knowledge as soon as possible.

Publishing a correction WITHOUT DISCUSSING IT FIRST WITH THE AUTHORS seems in "bad spirit". What if your correction needs a correction? "Errare humanum est, perseverare autem diabolicum."
The collectivity will benefit less from a chain of corrections than from a single well thought one.

Ok, this point makes sense. Of course, I will contact the original author if it is possible.

From your second paragraph, you seem to suggest to let the authors know the mistake, and then the authors correct it by themselves, acknowledging you only. I am confused. You seem to suggest us to contact the authors without having a completed correction paper on hand. If we don't write a rigorous paper on the mistake, I cannot be sure that my observation is correct. In this case, it will be very likely that our observation is incorrect, then we fall in to the "chain of corrections" you described.

We are getting lost in details because talking in general, when it all depends of how important the errors are! From small (e.g. indexing sums from 0 instead of 1, for many sums) to big (e.g. a serie is said to converge when it does not without a key additional hypothesis).
Specifically, I suggest to collaborate with the authors: 1) they have an incentive to correct their errors too, 2) they are likely to be one of your reviewers if you sent an independent article anyway.
